# Why does Windows ODBC API take input arguments as non-const?

Tags: c, winapi, odbc

The Windows ODBC API takes all string arguments as `SQLCHAR *` even when they are documented as input arguments. For example, the declaration for the function [SQLConnect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711810%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is:

```
SQLRETURN SQLConnect(
SQLHDBC        ConnectionHandle,
 SQLCHAR *      ServerName,
 SQLSMALLINT    NameLength1,
 SQLCHAR *      UserName,
 SQLSMALLINT    NameLength2,
 SQLCHAR *      Authentication,
 SQLSMALLINT    NameLength3);
```

There doesn't seem to be an obvious reason why non-const access to the data would be needed, and the API reference explicitly states those are input arguments.

What might be the reasoning behind the decision not to take string input arguments as const?

Answer (score 0):

Plain history. All these headers are 15+ maybe 20 years old. I am not sure it makes sense to update them today.

Answer (score 0):

`why non-const access to the data would be needed`

The system manipulates the original parameters for internal processing. Hence it should not be read-only parameters.

From the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711810%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) 
`If the data source name cannot be found or ServerName is a null pointer, the Driver Manager locates the default data source specification and connects to the associated driver. The Driver Manager passes to the driver the UserName and Authentication arguments unmodified, and "DEFAULT" for the ServerName argument.`
Clearly seems it manipulates the input arguments.

Comment: Do you have any reference for that?

Comment: To me that doesn't seem so clear at all. It could as well pass "DEFAULT" to the driver without manipulating the original data. And as the ServerName pointer given to SQLConnect can be a null, it has to be able to do that anyway.